# Generate dll file based on xaml and cs files

Tags: wpf, xaml, compilation

I have an application in WPF and I would do the following: In a folder I have a file .xaml that contains the screen, and a file .cs that contains the behavior of that screen. I need to generate a single .dll file from these two files (xaml an cs) and be able to access this .dll file within my application, so that this screen would make part of my application. I have no idea how to do this. Could anyone help me???
Thank's

Comment: I believe that the only way to do that would be to have each pair of XAML and .cs files in their own project, but that would be total overkill... why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)? It is useful for the scenario you describe, as long as you aren't trying to compile the screen at runtime. If that is what you're trying to do, I don't think you can associate a class with loose XAML.

If you have a `ViewModel`, and a `View` without code-behind, then you could potentially do this during the lifetime of the application. However, I think it will be far easier to compile these files, and have Prism load them as a module.